# Is it possible to use prepared statements in php to create an event?

Tags: php, sql, events

I'm trying to create an sql event with the following code

```
$query= "CREATE EVENT $this->eventId ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + interval 1 minute ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO UPDATE seats set seatStatus='free' where seatStatus='pending' and idSeat=(select idSeat from seats where seatNumber=$this->seatNumber AND idType=$this->seatType)";
```

it does not give any error code while executing it, but it won't create the event

I tried the bindParam method aswell,to pass the parameters to the query , it did not help

Comment: Can you show how you used that `$query` string?

Comment: Have you tried putting the property reads into curly brackets: e.g. `{$this->eventId}` ?

Comment: Okay. Is this MySQL? And are you using PDO?

Comment: *"I tried the bindParam method aswell,to pass the parameters to the query , it did not help"* - For some reason, I have a feeling you tried to pass the placeholders to a table/column. If that was the case, then you can't do that. PDO or MySQLi_ prepared statements don't support table/column binding.

Comment: The `$this` suggests you're using a separate (OOP) class with methods. Your question is unclear in that respect and more.

Comment: Yes, I'm using PDO for mysql, I did try to pass the placeholders to a table

Comment: I don't think MySQL supports CREATE EVENT in prepared statements. In https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html the "SQL Syntax Allowed in Prepared Statements" doesn't include EVENT.

Comment: Yes, I'm using another class that sends the variables via a post method

Comment: @Don'tPanic True but they tried to bind a table; see more comments (*"I did try to pass the placeholders to a table"*) and mine above.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I agree that does sound problematic. I'm just saying, I don't think you can create events this way regardless. I'm not 100% sure of that, though. It's not something I've tried to do myself, I'm just getting that from the documentation.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Ok. It's a first for me here in regards to what they're wanting to do. I would think that it theoretically could be done, of sorts I can't see why not. I don't have a web server of my own anymore so I can't test stuff anymore.

Comment: indeed it does not allow the create event query in a prepared statement, so my only option would be to pass the variables directly to the query correct?

Comment: Could you put this into a stored procedure, and execute it that way? That ought to work.